# How can I skip first item from Twitter Status feed, display next 4 items with PHP?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am setting up a series of Twitter feed displays on one page.  One shows the MOST RECENT status, in a particular fashion.  The other (I am hoping) will show the next 4 statuses, while NOT including the most recent status.  Here is part of the code that I think needs attention in order for this idea to work out:

```
$rss = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?
    screen_name='.$twitter_user_id);

        if($rss) {

            // Parse the RSS feed to an XML object.
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($rss);

            if($xml !== false) {

                // Error check: Make sure there is at least one item.
                if (count($xml->channel->item)) {

                    $tweet_count = 0;

                    // Start output buffering.
                    ob_start();

                    // Open the twitter wrapping element.
                    $twitter_html = $twitter_wrap_open;


                    // Iterate over tweets.

                    foreach($xml->channel->item as $tweet) {
```

Here is the website which has lent me the code for this task:

< [Pixel Acres - Display recent Twitter tweets using PHP](http://f6design.com/journal/2010/10/07/display-recent-twitter-tweets-using-php/) >

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop goes over each item in the feed. You want to skip certain elements based on the position in the feed, so you could add an index variable to the foreach and an `if` after the foreach:

```
 foreach($xml->channel->item as $i => $tweet) {
     if ($i == 0 || $i > 4)
           continue;
```

Comment: For some reason, this is still returning the strings as they were before--including the first string.  Do you know if using array_shift() would help make this problem come to a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I used an alternate method to solve the issue I was having.  It included using a string replace on the latest tweet's URL to obtain the Tweet ID, which then allowed me to query tweets using (Tweet ID - 1) as the max_id term.